# Django Template Aren't Loading

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I'm trying to load different html files into the base.html and they're not showing. Any ideas?

```
<body class="bg">
   <main class='text'>
      {% block carousel %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block info%}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %} 
           
      {% block mobile %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Are there any particular errors in the error console (for whatever browser you're using)?   What are the blocks like?

Comment: Update question with different html files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing template *inheritance* with template *composition*.

In template *inheritance*, you have a base page like `base.html`:

```html
<body class="bg">
   <main class='text'>
      {% block carousel %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block info%}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %} 
           
      {% block mobile %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
</body>
```

Then, you have a second template `shoes.html` that extends `base.html`. It inherits all the HTML from `base.html`, but fills in some custom content inside the blocks:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block carousel %}
<p>Carousel</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block info%}
<p>Info</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Content</p>
{% endblock %} 
           
{% block mobile %}
<p>Mobile</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Therefore, when you render it inside your view:

`views.py`

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/shoes.html', {})
```

you get this result:

```html
<body class="bg">
   <main class='text'>
      <p>Carousel</p>
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Mobile</p>
   </main>
</body>
```

I suspect that you have different HTML files named after each block (e.g. `carousel.html`, `info.html`). That's not how Django works (but it *is* how Ruby on Rails works). Is that what you were trying to do? If not, please update your question to clarify.